Is "Non-Trivial amount of work" a correct phrase?
I have been saying "Non-Trivial amount of work" for several years now to imply "sizeable/large chunk of work".
I am pretty sure I learned this phrase like hundreds of other phrases from Native English speakers.
But the dictionary meaning of the word trivial is different. Is the way I am using the word Trivial correct?

It's fine. There are dozens if not hundreds of published written instances of non-trivial amount of X for a wide range of different X's (work, time, capital, money, processing,...). But non-trivial doesn't mean sizeable/large - it means what it says - not small, not insignificant, not inconsequential.

The only thing that looks wrong is the capital 'T' - I would write it lower-case here.

How is the dictionary definition of "trivial" different?

This is a use of trivial which I believe started out as a term of art in mathematics, and then spread to programmers and techies in general. I would still regarded as technical jargon.

I mostly use "non-trivial" in a technical or engineering context- it might sound a little odd to non-technical ears. It means exactly what you think. To add some nuance, I typically say "it's a non-trivial task" when speaking of complexity or difficultly of the work, not necessarily amount. On the other hand, moving a thousand rocks from here to there is trivial in the sense of complexity, but takes a non-trivial amount of time and energy. It may be worth it to specify which one you're talking about!

I've heard the phrase used many times and have used it myself. "Non-trivial" is a funny way of saying "a lot" or "considerable" or "extreme". It's funny since it deliberately understates things, similar to how we say "not bad" when we mean "very good" ("I had that cake -- it wasn't bad") or when someone is completely drenched with rain you say "looks like you got a little wet".
My experience is as a math joke. It was common to find papers with phrases such as "...and it's trivial to prove supporting lemma X" where we'd spend 2 days trying to figure out how to prove it. As "trivial" became overused for problems which were actually difficult, saying a problem was "non-trivial" became a funny of saying "so difficult that no one could call it 'trivial'".
So it's fine to use "non-trivial" (to mean "difficult"), but only when it's appropriate to make a small joke.

This is accurate. It is often not used seriously but for comic effect.

I've used "non-trivial amount of work" many times at work because some people, usually management, have a skewed understanding of how much can go into certain kinds of technical tasks. In those situations, I've used "non-trivial" specifically to respond to an implication that the work to complete a task is trivial. Non-real example: Management asks for a maintenance window of 2 minutes to be reduced to a zero-downtime because 2 minutes seems so short, so that task seems easy. I would respond that it's a "non-trivial amount of work" to eliminate those last two minutes.

@Lambie I've used "non-trivial" (usually followed by "amount of work") quite a bit and have heard it used a good amount as well, but never as a joke. In my experience it is used as a way to emphasize that, for example, some task will require an amount of work that is not small, while avoiding implying that the amount would also be exceedingly great.

I don't think it's used as a joke. Like others said, if I told my boss something would take a "non-trivial amount of work", that means it can't be done in 5 minutes, but doesn't mean it's big.

-1 "Not bad" does not mean "very good". Goodness is a spectrum, not binary - "not bad" should be close in meaning to "decent", a far cry from "very good". In the same way, "non-trivial" does not mean "difficult".  It's also not a joke - I hear it used all the time in eg. academic papers.

@ToddWilcox Thanks, since I think that supports my first point, that "non-trivial" is most commonly used in reaction to the word "trivial". It's not a top choice otherwise, such "how much work do you think this would be?"

@Herohtar Sure, not a joke, since a joke typically conveys no information. But not as serious or precise as a direct answer such as "a few hours", "difficult" or "might not be possible, I'd have to think about it." The best I could think of were "a funny way of saying" and "deliberate understatement for comic effect". I'm not sure there's a word or short phrase for that.

As a familiar phrase, it has started to acquire a specific meaning, at least in the computing circles I frequent. It specifically says that the amount of work involved is unknown, except that it will clearly be significant. When you don't know if a job will take a week, three months or five years, this phrase may well get used.

"non-trivial" isn't a joke, and it doesn't mean "a lot" or "difficult". If a task of work is trivial you might not need to account for it in a larger plan, but often a seemingly small and unimportant task needs to be accounted for (for a variety of reasons) so you would raise the point upgrading the servers is an automated process but organising and scheduling it is a non-trivial task. Similarly, the cost of upgrading the component is very low, but at scale it is non-trivial half a penny per item is nothing, but we make many millions each month so it is not something to ignore.

also non-trivial is similar to the expression non-zero which we use a lot in networking. It takes a non-zero amount of time to transmit data, it doesn't matter how long it takes but we must account (in our system design) for some latency.

adding a fuel filter at this point will result in a non-trivial increase in flow pressure. It might be a tiny amount in the grand scheme, but we need to be aware of it.

@OwenReynolds I'm saying "non-trivial" isn't a "comical" or otherwise funny at all way of saying something, and it's perfectly fine to use it in a serious setting where making jokes is inappropriate because it is in no way making a joke or anything of the sort, based on my experience in the software engineering world. Maybe it is different for other fields.

As an addition to the good comments/answers, here's an example that may clarify the meaning of the word.
Suppose a new car engine component has been developed, and in its first two years of production five million units have been manufactured. However reports are starting to appear suggesting a problem with the component.
When the first complaint was made, we might think of that as trivial. Maybe it was a one off fault. Maybe it wasn't a fault at all, but something else happened to the car and the new component was blamed.
But then there's a second complaint. And a third. Then 5, or 10, or 30. At some point we will reach a number which is still small as compared with the millions of units manufactured. But now it is non-trivial. It is no longer unimportant, because the point has been reached where there is a real question about the general reliability of the component.

Reminded me of Vanilla ice cream complaint of General Motors.  https://www.marketcalls.in/fun/vanilla-ice-cream-that-puzzled-general-motors-amazing.html

Thanks James, what a brilliant story!

The meaning of non-trivial can just be derived from the individual words of the phrase:

not trivial : SIGNIFICANT, IMPORTANT

M+W
As @FumbleFingers said, the phrase doesn’t mean sizable or large.  In fact, M+W’s first usage example includes small:

a small but nontrivial amount

We shouldn’t overthink as this isn’t an example of litotes:

the use of a negative or weak statement to emphasize a positive meaning, for example he wasn’t slow to accept the offer (= he was quick to accept the offer)

OLD defines litotes.

Work (especially tech work) is, as you say, frequently described as “non-trivial amount of work”, but that is not typically used to say that it is a large amount of work, unless you are trying for understated humor.
Quite frequently non-tech works have a distorted view of how much effort doing something with computers is — things that are actually easy are seen as hard, and things that are hard or impossible are seen as easy.  LLM are seen as actually being close to sci-fi artificial intelligence for instance, real life Pinocchio’s or Skynet.
In short, it says if you want this work done, we’re going to need to talk about it, it’s not something trivial like asking for extra ketchup on your hotdog.

Trivial has nothing (inherently) to do with size
Something is trivial if it is insignificant or unimportant within the relevant context. Often, this will mean that it isn’t big either, but not necessarily.
For example, a person might have a visual impairment, say, a slight short-sightedness. If this doesn’t require correction for everyday living, it’s trivial. But, if it prevents you from pursuing your life’s ambition to be a fighter pilot, it’s not trivial.
Alternatively, consider a software fault in a motor vehicle. Let’s say it only happens once every 50 hours of operation. If it’s in the entertainment system, it’s trivial. If it’s in the braking system, it’s non-trivial.
In the context you are using, “Non-Trivial amount of work”, the context is clear that you are talking specifically about the amount of work, rather than, say, the difficulty or importance of the work. It doesn’t mean (necessarily) a large amount of work, it means enough work that it will have a negative impact on other tasks.

Of course, "non-trivial" is modifying the word "amount", that's what makes it about size.

Yes, but finding a really good example would be a non-trivial amount of work.

It's true that "trivial" is not an exact synonym for "small", but your expression is still correct. Merriam-Webster gives the definition, "of little worth or importance." So, literally speaking, "not trivial" might mean "significant" rather than "large," but "a significant amount of work" is still what you meant.
As an aside, this is a figure of speech called litotes where you make a point by saying its opposite is false. And there can be some ambiguity. Sometimes, if you say "not small", you really just mean that it might be medium sized or large. But sometimes you mean that it's huge. Context is needed.
And non-trivial is the same.

I am going to disagree that saying a task is "non-trivial" is any kind of joke when reporting the implications of taking on such a task to management.
My experience is that saying a task is non-trivial in a commercial setting means

The task will have a cost in terms of resources needed to solve it
It may require work outside of its apparent scope - not everything is as simple as it appears on the surface.
"non-trivial" can be used by the speaker to warn that the task has the potential to incur cost overruns that would vastly exceed management's expectations - and should it do so, the speaker warned them of it beforehand.

In other words, if you hear that a task should be considered non-trivial, inquire further before agreeing to pay for it!

As a sort-of mathematician, if I say that a question is non-trivial, I usually mean that I can't immediately give the answer, but I can probably tell you within a week if you really need to know. I intend to say that it is probably not all that hard, but on the other hand not trivially easy, and I might have to work on it a bit to know just how easy. I dont have enough insight to give the answer, but enough to know what finding the answer might involve. It sometimes happens that once the question has been asked, I suddenly find the needed insight, and say, "Oh yes, it is trivial!" It can have a range of meanings.
I think the non-technical extensions might be; "I think I can do this, but I will have to put something else aside". Alternatively, "This might seem trivial to you, but Im fairly sure it isn't"

You could approximate "trivial" with "basic", as in "not advanced / substantial".
The background is in classical (and thus later medieval) education in Europe; the seven "arts" were divided into "trivium" and "quadrivium" (the roots of the words simply indicate "the three" and "the four" out of the total of seven - "vium" means a place where roads meet, so roughly "three roads" or "three ways") where you were expected to learn the trivium first, before proceeding to the more demanding quadrivium. Thus, "trivial" in the strict sense means "belonging to the trivium".
Trivium consisted of grammar, logic, and rhetoric; quadrivium comprised arithmetic, geometry, music, and astronomy. In other words, you need to learn to speak and reason before you move on to the more demanding applications of these skills.
